# Link between Alloy vars. and primary vars. and Alloy relational variables

Tags: alloy

I can't seem to understand the meaning of the `vars.` and `primary vars.` numbers that are displayed when solving is done. The Alloy book in section 5.2.1 explains that Alloy relational variables are mapped to boolean variables associated to the tuples of each relation. but I don't understand the correspondence between this definition of variables and the variable counts displayed in the gui. For example when this code is run (I am using the Alloy Analyzer 4.2 build date: 2012-09-25 15:54 EDT.):

```
sig A {}

pred show {}
run show for 2
```

it displays

```
0 vars. 0 primary vars. 0 clauses.
```

although there there exists one relation. And when this code is run :

```
sig A {}
fact {no A }
pred show {}
run show for 2
```

the variables count is like this :

```
6 vars. 2 primary vars. 5 clauses.
```

I can understand that maybe the 2 primary vars correspond to the max 2 elements of set A but I don't understand what are the 4 more variables that are enumerated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, primary variables are the variables that correspond to instances of your declared signatures. Their number represents all instances created in the whole Alloy universe. On the other hand, the total number of variables is usually greater, since it also reflects the variables that are needed to represent given facts when encoded into the SAT formula. (Some details about the statistics, of the KodKod underlying solver, can be found [here](http://alloy.mit.edu/kodkod/release/current/doc/kodkod/engine/Statistics.html).)

Therefore, in your second example, the number of primary variables is 3 due to the limit on the instances of signatures to 2. (E.g. if you add another signature, the number of primary variables will be 4.) The number of variables in total reflects the total number of variables in the (CNF) encoding of the formula, which in turn depends on the specific facts you've declared. Note that, in the first example, there are no variables needed since there is nothing to check (and solver does not need to emit anything).